# How to store custom logs to database

Tags: database-design

I would like to ask how you would suggest to save logs of some process (let's say measuring temperatur from multiple weather stations) to database. The problem I have is that I want to have logs immutable so they should be not effected when for example name of weather station changes -> so I guess I would need to create copy of weather station. But I would end up with copy of weather station for each temperatur measurement. Let's say that there would be also some reference temperatur through year stored in weather station so I would need to copy this one too. It would be so wasteful.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: I know I should not store one value twice but in that case I would end up with something like TABLE[weather_station_id, weather_station_name_id, weather_station_ip_address_id ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started:

Normalizing your example will look like this when your current schema is

```
weatherstation_id | weatherstation_name | weatherstation_ip_address | temperature | measure_date
```

start by breaking up into 2 tables where one holds only information about the weather station and your second table contains only measurement data

Table *Weather_Station*

```
id | name | ip_address
```

(I prefer short names that do not repeat what is already contained in the table name - and it's also a strong hint you need to normalize if the field isn't about the table/entity or a *Foreign Key*)

Table *Measure*

```
date_time | measure | weather_station_id
```

`weather_station_id` is now a foreign key related to your `Weather_Station` table.

Now you are able to change the name and IP address of your weather station without having to modify any measure records.

To retrieve your data, you'll `JOIN` your tables when querying:

```
SELECT
    wst.name,
    wst.ip_address,
    mes.date_time,
    mes.measure
FROM Measure mes
INNER JOIN Weather_Station wst ON wst.id = mes.weather_station_id
```

As with reference data points, it's just the same: Put them in a table of their own an include a foreign key to the `Weather_Station`

Table *Reference_Measure*

```
weather_station_id | reference_date | temperature
```

To include a reference value to your Measurement query, you'll `JOIN` your *Reference_Measure* table based on the weather_station_id and date and time truncated to the desired precision (month, day or hour) you plan to have as a reference date.

---

Next consider you have more data about the device installed in your weather station than just the IP address, like for example the board serial number.

Go ahead and break up that table again:

Table *Weather_Station*

```
id | name
```

Table *Device*

```
id | modelname | ip_address | serialnumber | weather_station_id
```

Now you are even able to swap out a broken device or change its IP address without having to change your weather station data or measurements data.

Taking this even further, you could consider to have the `device_id` in your *Measure* table instead of `weather_station_id`. Doing so, you'd be able to identify measurements that have been taken by a device that turned out to be broken.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I probably didn't described my problem good enough. I agree that the solution you provided is great (I wanted to go that way) but I have problem that I need to keep the temperature logs immutable (not change them). What I want to do is that I want to store the temerature with informations about weather station and all it's atributes to log (I don't mean to store it in one table just to have oportunity to get it by joining from database) but they can not change when I change informations about the weather station.

Comment: For example I make measurement of temperatur in my app so I would create it that way how you proposed but than I changes the name of weather station and I want to get my log (the temperature measurement) but I want to receive result with the old name. I hope it is clearer now. Once more thank you so much for your time and that you have patience with me.

Comment: In that case, you could historize your weather_station data and JOIN like you would do with reference measures to get the matching weather station name at that point in time without the need to mutate your measurement logs.

Comment: Ok, I understand could you just try to describe the suitable scheme? Would it be something like Weather_Station[id, name_id, ip_address_id ... many more information] and then Name[id, name, change_time], Ip_Address[id, name, change_time] Or you are thinking about something else?

Comment: It's hard to come up with a real schema without knowing the whole story. As a general goal, I'd try to design to 3NF and look into [SCDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) to cater for the historisation needs (Type 4).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Thank you once more this is really exactly what I was searching for! I am sorry that I wrote my question unclearly for the first time. Thank you that you didn't lost your patience with me.